# How can I show the Pylint score in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

How can I get Visual Studio Code to display the Pylint Score for the current workspace (better if for each of the files)?

I have generated `.pylintrc` and put it in the master folder; running Pylint from the command line displays the score. But without any score displayed with the Visual Studio Code Python plugin - only the Pylint messages.

Comment: me too looking for the same if you find any let us know.  such an underrted feature to have in vscode.

Comment: me too came looking for same feature here...

Comment: there's a 60 day window opportunity to vote on [this particular feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17003) somewhere in 2021, and it's closed now and not implemented.